# Pointwise Kato inequality, across the zero set

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

On a Riemannian space, let $T$ be a smooth 2-tensor and let $f$ be a smooth function, with $|T|^2=f^2.$ Does it follow that $|\nabla f|^2\leq|\nabla T|^2$?

I know that
$$f^2(|\nabla T|^2-|\nabla f|^2)=\frac{1}{2}|T_{ij}\nabla_kT_{pq}-T_{pq}\nabla_kT_{ij}|^2,$$
but this only gives the inequality when $f$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 2):

Your computation proves the inequality at all points where $f\ne 0$. It's also clearly true at all points where $\nabla f=0$. So consider the set $S$ of points where $f=0$ and $\nabla f \ne 0$. Since you're assuming $f$ is smooth, the regular level set theorem (also known as the [preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem)) shows that $S$ is an embedded codimension-$1$ submanifold, so its complement is dense. Therefore, by continuity, the inequality holds at points of $S$ as well.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to prove in general using a differential identity, as in the $f\neq 0$ case? For instance, would the result still be true if $f$ and $T$ are only differentiable?

Comment: @QuartoBendir: If $f$ and $T$ are of class $C^1$, then the same proof goes through. But if they're merely differentiable but not continuously so, I don't know the answer.